# XCode without Apple developer account: unable to install .ipa file

Tags: xcode, ipa, apple-developer

I have created an IPA file for my app, and I would like to test it on different devices.

I don't have apple developer account yet (i will purchase it once tests will be fully successful).

I installed the app with Xcode to my IPhone successfully, but I cannot do the same on other IPhones... I tried to sign the IPA with the IPhone owner account, but i got the same error message :
"Unable to install "app.ipa""

Do you have any idea what could be the error and how i could solve this ?
Purchase apple developer account is the only solution ? Even for testing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Purchase apple developer account is the only solution?

Yes. The ability to run an app on devices is exactly what a paid developer membership buys you.